# Probability Theory Bunny Question

Tags: probability

Each bunny is individually ready for the big mission with probability p. If I have n bunnies and need k for the mission, find the expected number of k-large squads I can form with bunnies ready for the mission.

I said that for binomial distribution we have $$P(X=x) = \binom{n}{x}p^{x}(1-p)^{n-x}$$

So then $E(X) = x*P(X=x)$, professor said this isn't right so I was wondering what I did wrong?

Comment: Sorry first time posting a question not sure why its formatted like that. the formula for P(X=x) should all be on one line.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: First, $x P(X=x)$ is a function of an integer $x$, so it can't be the expectation of a random variable which is just a number. Second, be careful to distinguish between the expectation of the number of ready bunnies (which is close to what you wrote down) and the expectation of the number of $k$-element sets of ready bunnies.

Comment: @Greg Martin, Oh yeah I meant to say that E(X) is the sum from x=0 to n of x*P(X=x). And then I defined X as the number of bunnies that are ready out of the group of n bunnies.

Comment: So what I have gives me the expected number of bunnies that are ready but not the expected number of k-element sets of ready bunnies?

Comment: Yes, for example, make sure you are accounting for the fact that if $k=3$ and $X=7$, only $2$ teams of $k=3$ bunnies would be ready for the mission

Comment: @DarkLordOfPhysics That's not right. If $X = 7$ and $k = 3$ there are in fact $35$ possible squads :)

Comment: You are right, I forgot they are not all identical bunnies

Comment: That's not quite right either. I think you were thinking about forming a maximal number of disjoint squads of identical bunnies.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. Would it be better to describe this as saying there are $2$ team slots, each composed of $k$ slots of bunnies in this case?

Comment: My source of confusion was I misinterpreted what was being asked for as "the expectation of the maximal number of disjoint $k$-squads (independent of their composition) that could be sent on the mission" and neglected that it was asking about the number of ways that $X$ (distinct) ready bunnies could be used to *form* a *single* $k$-squad (distinct up to a permutation of its members).  Thank you for the correction!

Answer (score 1):

Continuing from the discussion in the comments:

The random variable $X$ you described (binomially distributed) is the number of bunnies which are ready for the big mission. So, $\mathbb{E}(X)$ is the expected [number of bunnies which are ready for the big mission].

We want to find the expected [number of squads of $k$ bunnies which are ready for the big mission], so we should make a new random variable! Let $Y$ be the number of squads of $k$ bunnies which are ready for the big mission.

You should find the PMF of $Y$, and use this to compute $\mathbb{E}(Y)$, which will be the expected [number of squads of $k$ bunnies which are ready for the big mission] -- exactly the quantity you want to find!

Or alternatively, you can try to find a formula for $Y$ in terms of $X$, then use the PMF of $X$ to compute $\mathbb{E}(Y)$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to come up with a PMF for Y. Since each group of k has an equal choice of being selected can we consider it a binomial distribution. Furthermore, could we say that P(Y=y) = C(E(X), y)*p^y*(1-p)^(E(X)-y)

Comment: "Each group has an equal choice of being selected" doesn't make sense here. We want to count the *number of possible squads*. There's nothing about selecting each squad with some probability, or anything like that.

Comment: Oh okay, I just thought since it was a pmf there had to be something involving probability in there. So is it just E(Y) = C(E(X),y). Since this is counting the total number of groups you could make out of the expected number of ready bunnies?

Comment: thoughts on this ^ @diracdeltafunk

Comment: Or, should I use the fact Y=C(X,k). And then somehow use the PMF for X? I'm confused how that process would work.

Comment: The later seems appropriate in that the PMF for $X$ gives the probability of having a particular number $x$ of bunnies ready and $Y={X \choose k}$ specifies how many ways there are to form a $k$-squad from said $x$ bunnies. The expected number of ways to be able to form a $k$-squad is then the sum, weighted by probability, of the number of formable squads expressed in terms of $x$ over the sample space of $X$.  Please correct me if this incorrect @diracdeltafunk

Comment: Yes, $Y$ is exactly equal to $\binom{X}{k}$. So $\mathbb{E}(Y) = \mathbb{E}(\binom{X}{k}) = \sum_{x=0}^n \binom{x}{k} P(X=x)$.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers and comments are unnecessarily complicated.

There are $\binom nk$ groups of $k$ bunnies, and for each such group the probability that its bunnies are all ready for the mission is $p^k$ (assuming that by “individually” you mean “independently”).

Thus, by [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Properties) the expected number of groups of $k$ bunnies that are ready is $\binom nkp^k$.

Comment: Yes, this is the result I ended up at. I used the indicator function in the sum to reach this result, but this explains it much nicer. Thank you for the help!